# Keystore for public key encryption

Tags: encryption, saml, keystore, signature

I'm encrypting some SAML Assertions with a public key received from a vendor (for use within an IDP initiated workflow).

Is it possible to add that public key to a keystore instead of needing to create a credential, like so:

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(certFileStream)

BasicX509Credential credential = new BasicX509Credential()
credential.setUsageType(UsageType.ENCRYPTION)
credential.setEntityCertificate((java.security.cert.X509Certificate) cert)
credential.setPrivateKey(null)
```

The reason I'm interested is because I also have to sign the SAML, using my own private key - which I resolve the credential from my keystore. So it would seem more straight forward to keep them all in the same place.

Comment: You can store the certificate in a keystore and extract it before generating the credential

Comment: Any ideas on how you might do that?

Comment: I'm trying to do what you have done ("I'm encrypting some SAML Assertions with a public key received from a vendor (for use within an IDP initiated workflow).", but I have not got it working yet. Do you have any documentation or sample code which tells me how you have done it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your using OpenSAML. To read credentials from a Keystore in OpenSAML you use the KeyStoreCredentialResolver like so.

```
keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/path/to/my/JKS");
keystore.load(inputStream, "MyKeystorePassword".toCharArray());
inputStream.close();

Map<String, String> passwordMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
passwordMap.put("MyEntryID"), "MyEntryPassword");
KeyStoreCredentialResolver resolver = new KeyStoreCredentialResolver(keystore, passwordMap);

Criteria criteria = new EntityIDCriteria("MyEntryID");
CriteriaSet criteriaSet = new CriteriaSet(criteria);

X509Credential credential = (X509Credential)resolver.resolveSingle(criteriaSet);
```

More on using the resolver in OpenSAML on [this post](http://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/03/getting-credentials-in-opensaml.html) on my my blog

Answer (score 0):

You can store the certificate in a keystore and extract it before generating the credential. This code should work

Create keystore with a certificate

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");  
keyStore.load(null);  
KeyStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("keystore.jks");
keyStore.store(out, ksPassword);
out.close();
```

Load certificate from keystore

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");  
keyStore.load(  new FileInputStream("keystore.jks"),ksPassword);  
Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
```